# Does time slow down due to relativistic mass increasing?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, mass, time-dilation

I once heard of how the existence of time dilation means relativistic mass must increase to conserve momentum but wouldn't it make more sense that something moving relative to something else leads to mass increase for what ever reason and this mass increase makes it harder for objects to move meaning "time" dilates. In other words, time dilation is simply atoms or molecules moving slower due to an increase in relativistic mass.

Comment: *something moving relative to something else leads to mass increase* “Relativistic mass” is an outdated, obsolete, unnecessary, and confusing concept. It is no longer used in modern physics. Today when physicists talk about mass they mean Lorentz-invariant mass. It does not change with velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you heard about increase of mass related with 'Time Dilation' was absolutely wrong. Why? Einstein didn't even approve of relativistic mass. And in relativity as we know generally is that $$ m = \frac {m_{0}}{\sqrt{1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}}$$

was completely a fictitious quantity. In modern physics, it's no longer used and outdated as well. Einstein showed that for a massive object with energy '$E$' and '$p$' respectively $$ E^2 = (pc)^2 + (m_{0}c^2)^2$$

whereas, $$ E = \frac {mc^2}{\sqrt {1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}} $$
$$ p = \frac {mv}{\sqrt{1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}} $$

Now, according to 'Energy Momentum Relation', the mass is an invariant quantity independent of all reference frames. Inertial Mass of an object always remains the same.

Applying Newtonian Mechanics on relativity or Lorentz transformation creates the absolute confusion about relativistic mass whereas showing momentum as the product of the multiplication of mass and velocity is invalid in this case. The rate of change of the total momentum of a system of particles is equal to the sum of the external forces on the system.

So, this is case when a object moves so fast, terms get relativistic and it's harder to increase its velocity as momentum is multiplied with $\gamma$ where $$\gamma = \frac {1}{\sqrt {1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}}$$

And when you collide that moving object with another object, much amount of extra mass you get according to 'Energy mass equivalence' principle which was used for changing its momentum, right? Now this can be shown as $$ m = \frac {E}{c^2}$$

But theme really gets messed when you violate the conservation of mass. And more to say, relativistic effect cause atoms' disturbance where (Considering Lorentz contraction into account) atoms have to travel a longer distance and thus time according to any static reference frame is thus dilated as velocity remains unchanged.